# How to replicate elements in a vector (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, vector, duplicates, sequence, element

so I have a situation where I need to duplicate elements in a vector. So for example, I have a column vector A = [1,0,1,1,0,1,1]' and I want to duplicate each element 100 times, so I want to end up with [1,1,1,1,1,1....(100th one),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...(100th zero).........]', you get the idea. My original idea was to make an empty vector say B = []', then create a loop which goes through the elements in A then inserts them into B, if that makes sense?

```
B = []'
A = [1,0,2,1,1,1,0,1]' 
for i = 1:length(BS)
    B = B + A(i)*100
end
```

I know this is wrong, I just can't find out how to do this, I know you guys hate questions like this but I honestly have looked every where and can't find an answer. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try this - `reshape(repmat(A',[100 1]),1,[])`

Comment: Or B = kron(A,ones(100,1))

Comment: Or `B = A(ceil(1/100:1/100:numel(A)));`

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers guys, I'll stick with @Benoit_11 method, I think it's quite elegant ^^

Comment: @Benoit_11 Make sure to post that as an answer!

Comment: @Divakar Oops I can't since it's a duplicate... of a duplicate haha that's kind of funny :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 Damn that name also starts with `duplicating`..!